# Symfony: How to disable input TextType for name attribute inside CollectionType with own condition

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

(Symfony 5.2, doctrine, PHP 8.0)

Take a look at this sample code:
more described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('description');

        $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => TagType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add'  => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('name');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $tag = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            dd($tag); // empty because of prototype: true (as I said need it for adding new t

        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Tag::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
TABLES:

TASK: id, name
TAG: id, task_id, name
```

my problem:
I would like to set - HTML attribute disabled for input name that meets the condition.
I need to get Task ID inside TagType so I can check if this id is used in another table and if so - disable changing tag name.
I tried multiple things but nothing worked for me. 
The main problem is its a prototype (need it for adding/removing) and I don't receive tag id inside `$tag = $event->getData();` in TagType so I can't get task id.

any idea? I didn't found the same problem on the internet and I'm not able to figure it out alone.

Comment: Hello, can you provide the code where you use your "$tag = $event->getData();" please?

Comment: Hello, I updated the question - now it contains the place where I expect this data

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try is to use the `PRE_SET_DATA` event on the task form side to get the ID, and pass that ID to your tag form with the `entry_options`. Something like (not tested, but you'll get the idea) :

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('description');


        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $task = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $form->add('tags', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TagType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'task_id' => !empty($task) ? $task->getId() : null,
                ],
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_add'  => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ]);
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        // $options['task_id']
        // Use your taskId here. The value can be null, on the task creation form.
        
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Tag::class,
            'task_id' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm this works. I can remember I tried this thing but one core thing which I was missing - was adding it to default parameters. (Error message was something like this parameter options isn't allowed + list of allowed options - so it was a bit confusing)

Also, I'm currently facing another similar issue - I would like to receive tag_id inside TagType - but the problem is that it's still a prototype so I don't get an entity there. Do you have any idea about this one?

Comment: @Mury you can't have the Tag ID inside the prototype because it does not exist at that time. You can only have the ID for existing tags (after saving for example)